# Application OR Object Defined Error on a line using Sheets.Range.Offset

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a newbie. I have an excel file with 10 sheets, 6 sheets named after 6 employee names the next 3 with some information (irrelevant to my code) and the 10th sheet named Temp.

The employee sheets have the following data in each column (D&E are blank):

```
| A         | B                | C | D | E | F                          |
| 17-Sep-13 | ProjectA         | 6 |   |   | Report updated on this day |
| 18-Sep-13 | CBL Ideas - HMF  | 7 |   |   |                            |
| 18-Sep-13 | CBL Ideas - HMF  | 1 |   |   |                            |
```

I want to have all these data collated in the sheet named Temp as follows:

```
| A         | B         | C | D   |
| 17-Sep-13 | Project A | 6 | foo |
| 18-Sep-13 | Project A | 7 | foo |
| 18-Sep-13 | Project B | 1 | foo |
| 17-Sep-13 | Project A | 6 | bar |
| 18-Sep-13 | Project A | 7 | bar |
| 18-Sep-13 | Project B | 1 | bar |
```

Below is my code:

```
Sub ListRelevantEntries()
  Dim s As Integer
  Dim C As Range

  For s = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 4  
    If Sheets(s).Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp) _
          .Value = "Report last updated on this day" Then
      'Execution stops on the below line with an
      ' "Application-defined or object defined error"
      Sheets(s).Range(Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp) _
          .Offset(1, 0), Cells(Rows.Count, _ "A").End(xlUp)) _
          .Copy(Sheets("Temp").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))

      Sheets("Temp").Select
      Sheets("Temp").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Select
      For Each C In Sheets("Temp").Range(Cells(Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp). _
        Offset(0, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)).Cells
        C = Sheets(s).Name
      Next
    ElseIf Not Sheets(s).Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp) _
          .Value = "Report last updated on this day" _
          And Not Sheets(s).Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Value = "" Then
  MsgBox "Extra Words entered " & ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F") _
      .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value & " in " & Sheets(s).Name
    End If
  Next

  Sheets("Temp").Range("1:1").Delete  
End Sub
```

Sorry for such a long question. I couldn't think of any other way to explain!

Comment: `Cells` without a sheet qualifier refers by default to the ActiveSheet, so you should always use something like (eg) `Sheets(s).Cells(...`

Comment: @TimWilliams Would keep that in mind. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

The error will be a lot easier if you clean up your code. Add a worksheet variable at the start

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
```

Then after the first For statement assign the target sheet to it

```
  Set ws = Worksheets(s)
```

Notice I used `Worksheets(s)` not `Sheets(s)`. They are different, don't mix them. The `Sheets` collection can include Charts as well as Worksheets, it represents every tab. The Worksheets collection only contains Worksheet objects. In your `For` loop you used `Worksheets`,  then you used `Sheets` within the loop. This will break if any charts are in the workbook.

Okay, so now that you have this `ws` variable containing a reference to the worksheet, go ahead and replace all your `Sheets(s)` with `ws` inside the for-loop's body. While you are at it, fix all your calls to `Cells` and `Rows`. Anywhere you write something like `ws.Range(Cells(1, "F"))` you are making a mistake. `Cells` alone points to `ActiveSheet.Cells` where as you want `ws.Cells`. Otherwise you are trying to create a cross-worksheet range any time `ws` is not `ActiveSheet`. The same goes for other properties of a range, such as `Rows`. So now the line of code you're stopping on should be more like this:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp) _
      .Offset(1, 0), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
      .Copy Sheets("Temp").Cells(Sheets("Temp").Rows.Count, "A") _
      .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

Notice, I also removed the parentheses around the parameter you're passing to `.Copy`. In VBA you call a method without parentheses unless it returns a value. So `MyMethod "Value to pass"` or `result = MyMethod("Value to pass")` but not `MyMethod("Value to pass")`.

After fixing all that, if it still is producing the error, I'd recommend using the debugger. Open the watch window and start breaking the offending line into bits, examine them, and find the problem.

So first you might create a watch for `ws` and make sure it's the correct sheet. Then maybe edit that watch to be `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)` and see if that is getting the correct cell.

Oh, also, if you're doing it properly you shouldn't need to call anything like `Worksheet.Select` or `.Activate`. In fact, it's recommended you avoid those the vast majority of the time, unless you are interacting with the user by changing their view.

Comment: @AndASM Vow that was an amazing answer didn't just clear my doubt and make my code work, but also taught me a great deal. Thank you so much. I hope I'd be able to help people like this when I become reasonably knowledgeable :) Thank you once again..

Answer (score 0):

Replace with something like

```
With Sheets(s)
        .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Copy Sheets("Temp").Cells(Sheets("Temp").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My code worked with AndASM's answer above. However, your answer helped me note the use of With Statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you get the error since you did not return the reference to the sheet(s).
A quick fix is to add this:

```
Sheets(s).Select
```

prior line 6 or after line 4.

But for better coding, try using whats seen in [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select).
That link discusses how you can avoid using select by declaring and setting all your objects.

Comment: Went through the link given by you. Was very helpful. Thanks a lot!